# MySQL Workbench no permite uso de claves foraneas

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

[image]

Como se puede ver, estoy intentando añadir claves foraneas a una tabla "ESTUDIANTES".

Sin embargo, el programa no me permite hacerlo. Como se ve, es un problema de sintaxis y no de conexiones (ejemplo 120.35.2.blablalba.... en vez de localhost).

¿Que esta pasando?

No se si esto influya, pero estoy usando localhost con Xampp.

Comment: añade le script completo que estás intentando ejecutar, de ese modo será mas simple ayudarte

Comment: El problema es que en versiones más actuales de MariaDB no todas las instrucciones son 100% compatibles con las de MySQL, y Mysql Workbench te va a crear instrucciones para MySQL. En tu script quita la palabra `VISIBLE` y se debe solucionar. MariaDB por default pone los indices visibles.